# How to Prevent Negative Stock Qty Value In Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, inventory, cataloginventory

How do I prevent product stock qty value showing negative values in admin? I have set Backorders to "No Backorders" but still it's showing negative values. can anybody please help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom module and an event observer hook to the `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before` event then you can validate if the qty will be saved as negative or perform some action.

> Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<global>
...
    <events>
        <cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before>
            <observers>
                <namespace_module_stock_item_save_before>
                    <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                    <method>stockItemSaveBefore</method>
                </namespace_module_stock_item_save_before>
            </observers>
        </cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before>
    </events>
</global>
...
```

> Namespace/Module/Model/Observer.php

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
{
   public function stockItemSaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
        // Perform some action ...
   }
}
```

Now you can do with item qty as per your requirement.